# CSS wildcard selection and value check

Tags: javascript, css

A website has elements with the id names: `player_1`, `player_2` etc... but also elements with the id names `player_img` and `player_name` etc...

I want to get only the elements with the id `player_` and then an integer. How would I do that with CSS selectors?

I'm doing this in javascript (with the `querySelector` function), so would the simplest be to do it in two steps (first select all `[id^="player_"]`, then filter out those without an integer as last character)? Or is there a smart solution to this with only CSS selectors?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Try one of your suggested solutions and if you get stuck, edit the question.

Comment: The suggestion I made with first selecting all, then filtering out works. I was just interested to learn more about CSS and see if there were any smart combinations of functions I haven't learned or found online to do it in one line with CSS selectors :) (If there are none, that's an okay answer too)

Comment: is the range of integer defined?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not sure, but I can expect it to be below 20 and always over 1